# jsTree sub-nodes are not triggering ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jstree

I have the following HTML

```
<div id='jstree_demo'></div>
```

and I called the jsTree to initialize the tree

```
function set_tree() {
        $('#jstree_demo').jstree({
            "core": {
               "animation": 0,
               "check_callback": true,
               "themes": { "stripes": true },
               "data": {
                   "type": "POST",
                   "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   "url": function (node) { 
                    return node.id === '#' ? 'Data.aspx/get_node_root' :
                                             'Data.aspx/get_node_children';
                   },
                   "data": function (node) { 
                     return "{'id': '" + node.id + "'}"; 
                   }
             }
          },
            "plugins": [ "themes", "json_data", "ui"]
        });
 }
```

The call to the `get_node_root` is triggered as soon as I call the `set_tree()` function.

The returned data from server is:

```
[{"id":1,"text":"Grand Parent", "state":"closed"}]
```

The tree view is updated nicely. But the problem is that there is no arrow besides the folder, and it seems like the `Grand Parent` is not clickable.

I modified the server function `get_node_root` to make it return:

```
[{"id":1,"text":"Grand Parent", "state":"closed",
      "children":[
             {"id":20,"text":"Son 1"},
             {"id":30,"text":"Son 2"}
                 ]
}]
```

Then I loaded the page again. This time, the `Grand Parent` came along with his `Son 1` and `Son 2` Pre-loaded.

This time, the Grand Parent has a collapse arrow that I can use. But the sons don't. When I click the `Son`s or `Parent` no further call is made to the server. I am using Chrome Developer tool to see if there is any Server Error or javascript syntax error that might be stopping the call. Nothing is happening.

I even attempted this:

```
           ...
           "data": {
               "type": "POST",
               "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               "url": function (node) { 
                alert('node id is: ' + node.id); // The alert is: #
                return node.id === '#' ? 'Data.aspx/get_node_root' :
                                         'Data.aspx/get_node_children';
               },
            ...
```

The alert always displays the first node with id `#`

the alert does not appear again even if I click or expand any of the sons or parent.

I put a break point in the server code behind function that returns the parent and children. Except for the initial call, no further code is executed from the server...

I spend 5 hours trying to figure out what's wrong. I found related answers but none of their answers worked.

What am I doing wrong?